# Is there any feature to be enabled to make Delta lake in databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

Is there any feature to be enabled to make Delta lake in databricks. We have been using the parquet file in the Datalake. How can we make use of the Delta lake?

Is it only using the DELTA option or are there any features to be enabled?

Comment: To get started with using delta tables that's pretty much it. You can use `df.write.format('delta').save(<storage path>)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I followed the below syntax for creating a delta lake.  If you already have created a data frame then skip step 1 -> Go to step 2

**Step1: Create datafram**

```
file_location = "/FileStore/tables/NYCTripSmall.parquet"

df = spark.read.format("parquet") \
  .option("inferSchema", "True") \
  .option("header", "True") \
  .option("sep", ",") \
  .load(file_location)

display(df)
```

[image: Ref1]

**Step2: Create a table using DataFrame schema and write data**

You can save your file name in `saveAsTable`.The default file name should be `default.<file_name>`

```
df.write.format("delta").saveAsTable("demotb1")
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/tmp/delta/demotb1")
```

[image: Ref1]

[image: Ref3]